# Finding a complex function from one open set to another

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having problem with one specific type of sets, in the type of questions as the following:

Find an analytic 1-1 and onto function from one open set to another,
where the open set is missing a partial line:
for example :

Find an analytic 1-1 and onto function $f$ where:

$$f : \{z : \text{Im}(z) > 0 \} \setminus \{ it : 0 < t \leq h, \space h \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}\}\to \{z : \text{Im}(z) > 0\}$$

I would like to understand what is the best way to approach this type of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\phi(z)=z^2$ will take $\{z : \text{Im}(z) > 0 \} \setminus \{ i\,t : 0 < t \leq h, \space h \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}\}$ onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-h^2,\infty)$. Can you follow from here?

Comment: so than i would use \phi(z)=z + h^2 , and than \phi(z)= z^(0.5) ?

Comment: Yes, $\sqrt{z^2+h^2}$ will do it.

Comment: great, thanks :)

Comment: @copper.hat Why would I need a $\log$? May be I should add that the branch of $\sqrt{\ }$ is the one defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$ with $\sqrt{-1}=i$.